# What happens on closing ServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

What happens to client Sockets when I close a ServerSocket?
Will all connections made with serverSocket.accept() be closed as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Closing a `ServerSocket` will prevent new connections from being created, but it won't shut down existing connections.

`ServerSocket` is the listening socket involved only in creating a connection. The data communication is handled distinctly in the `Socket` returned by `ServerSocket.accept();`.

Comment: @grizeldi If this answered your question, please also accept (check) the answer to close your question.